# Qlikview Exclude a value from a list selection box

Tags: qlikview

I want to exclude a value from a list selection box.

The field is called `Status` and there are 4 values `All`, `Yes`, `No` & `Deleted`.

I want to NOT show `All`

I tried this but it just renames it to `0`

```
=IF(STATUS <> 'All', STATUS,0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qlikview is case sensitive, please keep that in mind.

If your field is called Status then

```
=If(Status <> 'All', Status)
```

also note adding null in the second parameter is redundant.

for a failsafe you could use

```
=If(lower(Status) <> 'all', Status)
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `0` to `null` removed it from the list for me.

```
=IF(STATUS <> 'All', STATUS,null)
```